# SFML pass renderwindow

Tags: c++, sfml

Im trying to make a game with the [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org).

I'm making a sf::RenderWindow but when I try to pass the window to another class
it fails. I can't access the window. Because I think it's good to make a separate 
class for handling events like 'close the window' etc. but then I can't access it. How 
can I fix this?

```
RenderWindow *window;  
window = new RenderWindow(VideoMode(768, 614), "Tower Defence ver 2.0");
```

Comment: Please show the code that does the "giving" and the "accessing".

Comment: Also next time please state which version of SFML you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Create yourself a header file and define your function like so

Header file

```
#pragma once

#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

class MyClass
{
public:
    sf::Sprite Sprite;

    MyClass();
    void Setup(sf::Texture& texture);
    void Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
};
```

Cpp file

```
#include "Bullet.h"

MyClass::MyClass()
{

}

void MyClass::Setup(sf::Texture& texture)
{
    Sprite.setTexture(texture);
    Sprite.setPosition(0, 0);
}

void MyClass::Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    window.draw(Sprite);
}
```

Then in your game loop for drawing you can call something like this

```
// myClass is an object of type MyClass
// renderWindow is your sf::RenderWindow object
myClass.Draw(renderWindow);
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need any more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

RenderWindow is in a namespace 'sf'

Maybe you have somewhere "using namespace sf;" and it's missing in other places.

Try prefixing it with sf::RenderWindow everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SFML are you using? This is not possible in SFML 1.6, but is in SFML 2.0 (upcoming version).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Foo
{
 public:
    Foo(sf::RenderWindow& ptrwindow)
     : ptrwindow(ptrwindow)
    {
          // your code here
    };
    sf::RenderWindow* window()
    {
         return &this->ptrwindow;
    }

  private:
        sf::RenderWindow ptrwindow;
};

int main()
{
 sf::RenderWindow* mywindow = new sf::RenderWindow()
 Foo myfoo(*mywindow);
 myfoo.window()->create(sf::VideoMode(768, 614), "Tower Defence ver 2.0")
}
```

Comment: You've got a memory leak, and I doubt `sf::RenderWindow` is copiable anyway.